# How to print one element of an array of an object in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

When i use var_dump on my variable $veraplicacao, i get the outcome bellow:

```
object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#351 (1) {
    ["items":protected]=>
        array(1) {
            [0]=> object(stdClass)#357 (11) {
                ["id"]=> int(1008)
                ["created_at"]=> NULL
                ["updated_at"]=> NULL
                ["nomeempresa"]=> string(11) "Teste teste"
                ["vagaaplicada"]=> string(6) "Testes"
                ["statusaplicacao"]=> int(4)
                ["pais"]=> string(6) "Brasil"
                ["estado"]=> string(16) "Distrito Federal"
                ["cidade"]=> string(12) "Plano Piloto"
                ["textocompleto"]=> string(16) "Teste 123"
                ["deleted_at"]=> NULL
            }
        }
}
```

How can i get only the "nomeempresa" value?

When i tried `$veraplicacao["nomeempresa"]`, i got the following error:

> Undefined index: nomeempresa

When i tried `$veraplicacao->nomeempresa`, i got the following error:

> Property [nomeempresa] does not exist on this collection instance.

When i tried `$veraplicacao->nomeempresa`, i got the following error:

> Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Possibly read the api and find the suitable "getter" method? Also `but doesn't work` is not at all helpful. Instead append the actual error or exception message to your post.

Comment: property you ask seems protected, so you can't access from outside the object ($veraplicacao["nomeempresa"] won't work). Apart from getter method,  you can't.

Comment: I added the error messages i get in my attempts.

Comment: Since it's a collection Did you tried to convert it to an array using ->toArray() method ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the attribute you're after you can use [first()](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-first):

```
$veraplicacao->first()->nomeempresa;
```

For more information on Collections I would suggest having a look at the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections).

---

Alternatively, since Collection implement [ArrayAccess](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) you could just use the index of the value in the array:

```
$veraplicacao[0]->nomeempresa;
```

Comment: Thanks, you solved my problem. I thought about trying $veraplicacao[0]->nome empresa, but i assumed it wouldn't work.

Comment: @NeyelsonAlves Glad I could help! You could always give me an upvote as well if you'd like? ;)

Comment: Sorry. I wanted to upvote your answer at the moment when i read it, but my low reputation doesn't allow me to cast votes yet.

Comment: @NeyelsonAlves Ah no worries :) Thank you anyway. Still Glad I could help!